# run script before boot options apears

Tags: security, assembly, passwords, password-protection, bios

Do any of you guys know if it's possible to run a script before i get the option to enter bios and before OS boots?
Example: i want to secure my pc with a script that requires me to press certain keys before the screen where i have the boot options apears (because passwords can be cracked, even bios, i don't trust them)

ps: i have been looking into this problem for a couple of hours and i couldn't find anything :(. i just need to know what language to use and where to insert the script.

thanks in advance!

Comment: a UEFI shell script could do this maybe (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)

Comment: The bios always gets first bite in the boot process. Do you have greater confidence in your own abilities in security than those of major bios vendors?

Comment: i don't want my script to be executed before bios. i just want it before the boot options apears so none of my os can be started.

Comment: @Awesome - your question states "possible to run a script **before i get the option to enter bios**". I assume that in your most recent comment, you're speaking of the boot options presented by the software on disk (i.e choose your OS to boot), and not not by the bios(choose your device sata1, sata2, etc). In that case - yes, you write the program that normally presents the boot options.You'll have to look into boot-loaders, MBR booting, partition tables and will need almost certainly to employ a multi-stage. Good luck, you're in for a long road. Have a look at: http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page

Comment: i was hoping for a quick way but i'll start studying. Thank you:)

Comment: i found this: Bios Interrupt Service Routine (ISR). any of you guys know something about it and if it might work this way?

Comment: i found this: Bios Interupt service routine. you think it might work with this low level instructions written in assembly?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and not so hard when system use UEFI BIOS, which is true for almost all modern systems.

Below solution is not exactly what you want but it is closest to what you can get.

What have to be done:

1. Write UEFI application in C that will wait until correct key combination pressed. If incorrect combination pressed then reboot or wait for another try.
2. Affect boot order using `bcfg` UEFI Shell command. You should use `bcfg` to put your application on top of boot order, so while device is booting first entry would be your application and not OS. How to use `bcfg` you can read [here, page 83](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Shell_Spec_2_0.pdf)

Couple notes:

- Biggest problem with this approach is that someone can enter BIOS setup and change order so application will not be executed, but this can be solved with securing setup menu with password.
- UEFI application have to be stored somewhere. It depends on storage medium, but application should be on UEFI readable partition, if someone will disconnect storage, then boot option will be skipped and protection will not work.
- Most UEFI BIOS vendors disable `bcfg` command since it can be dangerous, but this can be worked around by booting UEFI Shell from USB stick, if you have that option.
- Adding and removing devices in system affect boot order. You should test and see how adding various devices affect boot order in your system. Some additional configuration maybe needed in BIOS setup menu to make sure no new device will be probed before your application.

I wrote [blog post](http://blog.3mdeb.com/2015/11/21/uefi-application-development-in-ovmf/) about UEFI application development in emulated environment, which you should consider instead of experimenting on real hardware.